# Email server security

Tags: security, email-server

I am writing an email server from scratch. (For learning and also eventually replace my gmail). I have no plans to send via this server (only for receiving email). My goal is to not miss any non spam emails with max security as possible. So far What I have

1. Listening on port 25
2. Compulsory upgrade to STARTTLS
3. Letsencrypt tls certificate.
4. ESMTP and SMTPUTF8 enabled.
5. Server based on python aiosmptpd package

Questions:

1. Should I listen on more ports like 587, 445? If so what protocol should I use on those? no tls, STARTTLS or SMPTS(TLS over SMTP)?
2. I noticed that even when I had the wrong ssl certificate, gmail did deliver the mail. Does that mean any self signed certificate should be good enough or some providers do verify validity of the certificate?
3. Are there any popular senders that don't use STARTLS whose emails that I will miss?

Comment: Comment because link-only answers are discouraged:  This link might interest you.  https://blog.filippo.io/the-sad-state-of-smtp-encryption/